# How to fix "AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'code' in Python script?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, typeerror, attributeerror, cs50

I am working on a problem of CS50 harvard course. I wrote code that doesn't do the last step and gives me the error code above. I compared it to working code I found on this platform. Can someone tell me what the difference is and why my code it not working?

My code:

```py
from enum import Enum


class Operation(Enum):


    DELETED = 1
    INSERTED = 2
    SUBSTITUTED = 3

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name.lower())


    def distances(a, b):



        rows = len(a) + 1
        columns = len(b) + 1

        matrix = []

        for i in range(rows):
            matrix.append([])
        for i in range(rows):    
            for j in range(columns):
                matrix[i].append(j)

                if i == 0:
                    matrix[i][j] = (j, Operation.DELETED)

                elif j == 0:
                    matrix[i][j] = (i, Operation.INSERTED)

                elif a[i-1] == b[j-1]:
                    matrix[i][j] = (matrix[i - 1][j - 1][0], Operation.SUBSTITUTED)
                else:
                # Operations
                    ins_cost = matrix[i-1][j][0] + 1
                    del_cost = matrix[i][j-1][0] + 1
                    sub_cost = matrix[i-1][j-1][0] + 1

                # Get easiest method
                    cost = min(ins_cost, sub_cost, del_cost)

                    if cost == sub_cost:
                        op = Operation.SUBSTITUTED
                    elif cost == ins_cost:
                        op = Operation.INSERTED
                    elif cost == del_cost:
                        op = Operation.DELETED

                # Set cell value
                matrix[i][j] = (cost, op)
        return matrix
```

The Working code from someone else:

```py
from enum import Enum


class Operation(Enum):


    DELETED = 1
    INSERTED = 2
    SUBSTITUTED = 3

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name.lower())


    def distances(a, b):


        rows = len(a) + 1
        columns = len(b) + 1

        # List comprehension for 2D matrix
        matrix = [[None for _col in range(columns)] for _row in range(rows)]

        # Set base case empty string to empty string
        matrix[0][0] = (0, None)

        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(columns):

                if i == 1:
                    matrix[i][j] = (j, Operation.DELETED)

                elif j == 1:
                    matrix[i][j] = (i, Operation.INSERTED)

                elif a[i-1] == b[j-1]:
                    matrix[i][j] = (matrix[i - 1][j - 1][0], Operation.SUBSTITUTED)
                else:
                # Operations
                    ins_cost = matrix[i-1][j][0] + 1
                    del_cost = matrix[i][j-1][0] + 1
                    sub_cost = matrix[i-1][j-1][0] + 1

                # Get easiest method
                    cost = min(ins_cost, sub_cost, del_cost)

                    if cost == sub_cost:
                        op = Operation.SUBSTITUTED
                    elif cost == ins_cost:
                        op = Operation.INSERTED
                    elif cost == del_cost:
                        op = Operation.DELETED

                 # Set cell value
                matrix[i][j] = (cost, op)
        return matrix
```

full traceback:

> ```py
> Error on request:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
>         execute(self.server.app)
>       File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258, in execute
>         application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
>       File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
>         return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>       File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
>         response = self.handle_exception(e)
>       File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1748, in handle_exception
>         return self.finalize_request(handler(e), from_error_handler=True)
>       File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset6/hello/similarities/application.py", line 94, in errorhandler
>         return render_template("error.html", error=error), error.code
>     AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'code'
>      * Detected change in '/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset6/hello/similarities/helpers.py', reloading
>      * Restarting with stat
> ```

Comment: The loop parts are different `for i in range(rows):`

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: What's the content of your `application.py`, specifically, `errorhandler`?

Comment: Hi Idlehands, this is the content:

@app.errorhandler(HTTPException)
def errorhandler(error):

    return render_template("error.html", error=error), error.code

Comment: There's an issue in the distro error handler. Two small changes might help. 1) add `InternalServerError` to the `exceptions` import. 2) add two lines before the return in `errorhandler`......... `if not isinstance(error, HTTPException):
        error = InternalServerError()` These changes worked for me. That should show the _real_ error in flask console.